# porque me marca error en el int main diciendo no matching function FrecuenciasCardiacas?

Tags: c++

```
//Frecuencia Cardiaca
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class FrecuenciasCardiacas
{
private: //Atributos//
    string nombrePersona;

public: //Metodos//
    FrecuenciasCardiacas(string nombre)//Constructor
    {
        nombrePersona=nombre;
    }

void establecerNombrePersona(string nombre)//nombre
    {

        cout<<"Introduzca nombre: ";
        cin>>nombrePersona;
        nombrePersona = nombre;
    }

string obtenerNombrePersona() const
    {
        return nombrePersona;
    }

};

int main()
{
    FrecuenciasCardiacas ob1;
    ob1.obtenerNombrePersona();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Cuando intentas crear el objeto, intentas invocar el constructor por defecto:

```
FrecuenciasCardiacas ob1;
```

Se sabe que es el constructor por defecto porque no le estás pasando ningún argumento al constructor. Sin embargo, la clase `FrecuenciasCardiacas` no implementa dicho constructor, sino uno personalizado:

```
FrecuenciasCardiacas(string nombre)//Constructor
{
    nombrePersona=nombre;
}
```

Este constructor deshabilita el constructor por defecto salvo que lo implementes expresamente, cosa que no sucede.

Lo que sucede entonces es que el programa debería llamar a

```
FrecuenciasCardiacas::FrecuenciasCardiacas()
```

Pero ese constructor no está disponible.

Llegados a este punto hay dos posibles soluciones:

**Solución universal**: Implementa el constructor por defecto:

```
class FrecuenciasCardiacas
{
public:
      FrecuenciasCardiacas()
      { }
};
```

Si estás con C++11 o superior puedes usar `default`:

```
class FrecuenciasCardiacas
{
public:
      FrecuenciasCardiacas() = default;
};
```

**Solución personalizada**: Elimina el constructor personalizado. Esta solución solo es viable si dicho constructor no es necesario en absoluto. Al no implementar ningún constructor personalizado el compilador creará el constructor por defecto de forma transparente:

```
class FrecuenciasCardiacas
{
private: //Atributos//
    string nombrePersona;

public: //Metodos//

    void establecerNombrePersona(string nombre)//nombre
    {

        cout<<"Introduzca nombre: ";
        cin>>nombrePersona;
        nombrePersona = nombre;
    }

    string obtenerNombrePersona() const
    {
        return nombrePersona;
    }
};
```

Comment: Tienes razón! ya elimine mi respuesta. Gracias por la corrección!

Comment: @FranIslas no hacía falta eliminarla... podías haberla corregido

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he hecho de la siguiente manera, suelo hacer las clases de esta forma. Lo he probado y me ha funcionado, no sé si el funcionamiento será el que tú deseas, pero aquí dejo el código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class FrecuenciasCardiacas{

private: //Atributos

    string nombrePersona;

public: //Métodos

    FrecuenciasCardiacas(string); //Constructor

    void EstablecerNombrePersona(); //Método

};

FrecuenciasCardiacas::FrecuenciasCardiacas(string _nombrePersona){ //Inicializamos los atributos

    nombrePersona = _nombrePersona;

}

void FrecuenciasCardiacas::EstablecerNombrePersona(){

    cout << "Introduzca el nombre: ";
    cin >> nombrePersona;
    cout << "El nombre es: " << nombrePersona;
}

int main(){

    FrecuenciasCardiacas p1("Prueba");

    p1.EstablecerNombrePersona();


    return 0;
}
```

Como puedes observar, para inicializar los atributos utilizo `FrecuenciasCardiacas::FrecuenciasCardiacas(string _nombrePersona)`. En vez de crearlo dentro de la clase como lo has hecho tú. Con esto conseguimos que al crear el objeto de la clase, haga referencia a ese constructor.

Más abajo, al crear el objeto, es importante pasarle unos parámetros por defecto porque si no, nos dará un error al compilar: `FrecuenciasCardiacas p1("Prueba")`. No importa que valor le pongas en un principio porque luego al llamar al método, lo vas a cambiar por el que el usuario ha introducido.

Espero que te sirva. Si hay algún error, no dudéis en decídmelo. Un saludo.

Comment: Sería recomendable exponer un poco por qué tu forma de hacerlo soluciona el problema. Quien hace la pregunta no sabe por qué su código falla así que es conveniente detallar esas cosas

Comment: @eferion Gracias por decirlo, cuando tenga un hueco lo edito, un saludo!

Comment: Realmente es indiferente si la implementación se hace en la cabecera o en otro sitio. Se suelen separar por cuestiones de legibilidad y, en algunos casos, para reducir dependencias.

Comment: @eferion Gracias por el dato. Es que estoy aún en el primer año de la carrera y voy adelantando temario de programación por mi cuenta, por eso hay cosas que se escapan de mi entendimiento por ahora. Muchas gracias por responder y un saludo! :)